# Getting Blank on Old Java GUI Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: java, user-interface, window, frame, tic-tac-toe

Okay, so I wanted to learn GUI on Java, and on this book I used to have (It's 6 years old), I tried to copy a sample of their TicTacToe.java

Whether the statements used are a bit old, or I need to know some things before going out and trying these stuffs, I really couldn't figure out why nothing appears on the screen.

Here's my code (forgive the odd names and texts):

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FranzTicTacToe extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private Container c = getContentPane();
private JButton[][] gameBoard = new JButton[3][3];



private ImageIcon imageo = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\hftri\\Downloads\\tic.jpg");
private ImageIcon imagex = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\hftri\\Downloads\\tac.jpg");

private String turn = "Aloysius";
    boolean isGameOver = false;

    public void TicTacToe()
    {
        c = getContentPane();
        gameBoard = new JButton[3][3];
        imageo = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\hftri\\Downloads\\tic.jpg");
        imagex = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\hftri\\Downloads\\tac.jpg");
        isGameOver = false;
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        setTitle("Harambe");
        setBounds(250, 250, 300, 300);

        for(int column=0; column < 3; column++)
        {
            for(int row=0; row < 3; row++)
            {
                gameBoard[column][row] = new JButton();
                c.add(gameBoard[column][row]);
                gameBoard[column][row].addActionListener(this);
            }
        }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(isGameOver)
            return;

        JButton pressedButton = (JButton)e.getSource();
        int pressedColumn = -1, pressedRow = -1;

        for(int column=0; column < 3; column++)
        {
            for(int row=0; row < 3; row++)
            {
                if(gameBoard[column][row] == pressedButton)
                {
                    pressedColumn = column;
                    pressedRow = row;
                }
            }
        }

        //Game START

        if(gameBoard[pressedColumn][pressedRow].getIcon() != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if(turn.equals("Aloysius"))
        {
            gameBoard[pressedColumn][pressedRow].setIcon(imagex);
            turn = "Johpit";
        }

        else
        {
            gameBoard[pressedColumn][pressedRow].setIcon(imageo);
            turn = "Aloysius";
        }

        if(checkRow(pressedRow, imageo) || checkColumn(pressedColumn, imageo) || checkDiagonals(imageo))
        {
            isGameOver = true;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(FranzTicTacToe.this, "Aloysius is skrub", "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            turn = "Johpit";

            playAgain();
        }

        if(checkRow(pressedRow, imagex) || checkColumn(pressedColumn, imagex) || checkDiagonals(imagex))
        {
            isGameOver = true;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(FranzTicTacToe.this, "Johpit is skrub", "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            turn = "Aloysius";

            playAgain();
        }

        if(!isGameOver)
        {
            boolean tie = true;

                for(int column=0; column < 3; column++)
                {
                    for(int row=0; row < 3; row++)
                    {
                        if(gameBoard[column][row].getIcon() == null)
                        {
                            tie = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(tie)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(FranzTicTacToe.this, "Both of you are fukin skrubs", "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    isGameOver = true;

                    playAgain();
                }
            }

            if(!isGameOver)
            {
                setTitle(turn + "'s turn");
            }
        }
        boolean checkRow(int row, Icon player)
        {
            for(int column=0; column < 3; column++)
            {
                if(gameBoard[column][row].getIcon() != player)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        boolean checkColumn(int column, Icon player)
        {
            for(int row=0; row < 3; row++)
            {
                if(gameBoard[column][row].getIcon() != player)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        boolean checkDiagonals(Icon player)
        {
            if(gameBoard[1][1].getIcon() != player)
            return false;

            if(gameBoard[0][0].getIcon() == player && gameBoard[2][2].getIcon() == player)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        //Game Restarting Option

        void playAgain()
        {
            Object[] options = {"Yes", "No"};
            int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(FranzTicTacToe.this, "Pusta again?", "Query", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);

            if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
                dispose();
                FranzTicTacToe game = new FranzTicTacToe();
                game.setVisible(true);
            }
            else
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            FranzTicTacToe game = new FranzTicTacToe();
            game.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
            {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

            game.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

I made "Aloysius" a value for x and "Johpit" a value for o out of curiosity and fun.

Anyway, I'm new to GUI's in Java and I wanted to try this so that I could then learn each part of it slowly. All this code shows is a blank window. Any ideas?

Thank you :)

Comment: You never add anything to the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the constructor. Right now it uses the default constructor which essentially does nothing. It's probably a spelling error, but for the sake of understanding. If there is no constructor declared it will use the default constructor from `Object` class.
A constructor also needs to have the exact name as the class. So change your `TicTacToe` method to `FranzTicTacToe` constructor

```
 public void TicTacToe() // needs to be public FranzTicTacToe()
    {
        c = getContentPane();
        gameBoard = new JButton[3][3];
        imageo = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\hftri\\Downloads\\tic.jpg");
        imagex = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\hftri\\Downloads\\tac.jpg");
        isGameOver = false;
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        setTitle("Harambe");
        setBounds(250, 250, 300, 300);
    for(int column=0; column < 3; column++)
    {
        for(int row=0; row < 3; row++)
        {
            gameBoard[column][row] = new JButton();
            c.add(gameBoard[column][row]);
            gameBoard[column][row].addActionListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Thanks. I forgot to change that aswell.

Comment: no problem, you are welcome. this should fix the problem op has

Comment: I didn't know the Constructor has to be the same as the class so that really helped. It works now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You renamed the class, but forgot to rename the constructor, then fixed it the wrong way. Long story short:

```
public void TicTacToe()
```

should be

```
public FranzTicTacToe()
```